# Datatable error searching in html and php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I always get this error ***DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see [here](http://datatables.net/tn/3)*** when the page loads. 
i find it hard to use the search, pagination and entry functionalities. please i need your help.

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" style="width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th style="width: 23%">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
    <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Status='1' ";
          $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
          $query->execute();
          $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  if($query->rowCount() > 0){
      foreach($results as $result)
        {   ?>
        <tbody>   
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->UserId);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Username);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Fullname);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Position);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Gender);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Email);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Telephone);?></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
         <?php }} ?>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
      </table>   
</body>          
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable()
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried si9moy to rename id="dataTable"  into id="dataTable1"

Comment: You're calling `.DataTable` twice on the same table. Drop the first call in your script and try again.

Comment: i have drop `$('#dataTable').DataTable()` in the script. It's still not working.

Comment: i have renamed the to `id=dataTable1` still not loading.

Comment: You have an error in table code style="width="100%" in your table. Needs to be  style="width:100%;" Maybe table.js don't see table name cose wrong tags in <table>

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have error here: `style="width="100%"` needs to be `style="width:100%"`

Then you call your table twice `('#dataTable').DataTable`. As explained in [link YOU provided](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3).

There is also good [number of examples how to start using that plugin](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html).

Also you had 8 columns in table head and 7 in table body witch produces a error. You need to mach those numbers.

I have also included script into body and just to be sure called it on document ready. It works as seen below.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="dataTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th style="width: 23%">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>   
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
      </table>   
         
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
} );
    } );
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

So your code should be:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th style="width: 23%">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
    <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Status='1' ";
          $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
          $query->execute();
          $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  if($query->rowCount() > 0){
      foreach($results as $result)
        {   ?>
        <tbody>   
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->UserId);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Username);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Fullname);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Position);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Gender);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Email);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Telephone);?></td>
            <td>Missing column!</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
         <?php }
          ?>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Telephone</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
      </table>
<script>      
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  });
</script>      
</body>          
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to you all for your answers but when you try to use the search, the first row give you **No matching records found** and the other rows remains when the search item is not the first row.